# Output of wc -l without file-extension

Tags: linux, bash, cut, file-extension, wc

I've got the following line:

```
wc -l ./*.txt | sort -rn
```

i want to cut the file extension. So with this code i've got the output:
number filename.txt

for all my .txt-files in the .-directory. But I want the output without the file-extension, like this:
number filename

I tried a pipe with cut for different kinds of parameter, but all i got was to cut the whole filename with this command.

```
wc -l ./*.txt | sort -rn | cut -f 1 -d '.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have newlines in your filename you can use `sed` to strip out ending `.txt`:

```
wc -l ./*.txt | sort -rn | sed 's/\.txt$//'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i used the rev-command but sed also works!

Comment: It is your choice but in place of a single `sed` using  `rev + cut + rev` (3 commands) is totally unnecessary and inefficient.

Comment: Thats true. I replaced rev now with sed. Same output, but less code.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, `cut` doesn't have a syntax for extracting columns according to an index from the end. One (somewhat clunky) trick is to use `rev` to reverse the line, apply `cut` to it and then `rev` it back:

```
wc -l ./*.txt | sort -rn | rev | cut -d'.' -f2- | rev
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` in more generic way to cut off whatever extension the files have:

```
$ wc -l *.txt | sort -rn | sed 's/\.[^\.]*$//'
 14 total
  8 woc
  3 456_base
  3 123_base
  0 empty_base
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach using proper *mime type* (what is the extension of `tar.gz` or such multi extensions ? )

```
#!/bin/bash

for file; do
    case $(file -b $file) in
        *ASCII*) echo "this is ascii" ;;
        *PDF*)   echo "this is pdf" ;;
        *)       echo "other cases" ;; 
    esac
done
```

This is a *POC*, not tested, feel free to adapt/improve/modify

Comment: thats not exactly what i wanted, but thanks for your help anyway.